# How to print a return value from a function inside a class

Tags: python, function, tkinter, return, return-value

I am building a simple program that will compare two files. I already have the main code finished for the program now I am just working on implementing a GUI for it.

So my issue arises when trying make a button that when pressed will allow the user to choose a file then read that file. That is one function. The other button will compare two files, one was the one that the user chose and the other is a another file. So this is another function. So I need the return value from the first function to input it into the other function.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *




def make_dict(data):
    return dict((line.split(None, 1)[0], line)for line in data)


class myButtons:
    def __init__(self, master):
        firstFrame = Frame(master)
        firstFrame.pack()

        self.openLogButton = Button(firstFrame, text="Browse", command=self.getFileInfo)
        self.openLogButton.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(firstFrame, text="Print", command=self.compareAction)
        self.printButton.pack()

        self.quitButton = Button(firstFrame, text="Quit", command=firstFrame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack()

        self.scroll = Scrollbar(firstFrame)
        self.inputText = Text(firstFrame, height=4, width=50)

        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.inputText.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        self.scroll.config(command=self.inputText.yview)
        self.inputText.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)

        self.logFile = self.getFileInfo()

        thisIsTest = self.getFileInfo

    def printMessage(self):
        print "This works"
        test = self.inputText.get("1.0", END)
        print test

    def getFileInfo(self):
        return askopenfile(mode='rb')

    def compareAction(self):
        def process(infile, outfile, keywords):
            keys = [[k[0], k[1], 0] for k in keywords]
            endk = None
            with open(infile, 'rb') as fdin:
                with open(outfile, 'ab') as fdout:
                    fdout.write("<" + words + ">" + "\r\n")
                    for line in fdin:
                        if endk is not None:
                            fdout.write(line)
                            if line.find(endk) >= 0:
                                fdout.write("\r\n")
                                endk = None
                        else:
                            for k in keys:
                                index = line.find(k[0])
                                if index >= 0:
                                    fdout.write(line[index + len(k[0]):].lstrip())
                                    endk = k[1]
                                    k[2] += 1
            if endk is not None:
                raise Exception(endk + "Not found before end of file")
            return keys
        start_token = self.inputText.get("1.0", END)
        end_token = "[+][+]"
        split_start = start_token.split(' ')
        outputText = 'test.txt'

        print self.logFile

        # for words in split_start:
        #     process(self.getFileInfo, outputText, split_start)


root = Tk()
b = myButtons(root)

root.mainloop()
```

For right now I am just trying to test if my `compareAction` function received the return value from `getFileInfo` function. So far when I try to `print self.getFileInfo` I am treated with this result: `<bound method myButtons.getFileInfo of <__main__.myButtons instance at 0x100863ef0>>`

which I believe is the memory address of the function rather than the value the function has when the file is read.

The idea is simple. User chooses a file to open, that file is opened and read then returned after that return value is used in the compareaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think about solving this question is by adding another function. Try changing getFileInfo(self) to this:

```
def getFileInfo(self):
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename()
    return open(filename, mode="rb")
```

It essentially does the same thing as your previous function, except it makes the file global. Then make another function called getFileName(self) like this.

```
def getFileName(self):
    return filename
```

Now when you call the process function, use self.getFileName instead of self.getFileInfo:

```
process(self.getFileName, outputText, split_start)
```

If you are wondering why you get the bound method output, it might be because you are opening the file and not reading it. Essentially when you run print self.logFile, it is returning a file object. This is what happened when I tried your printing an open file on my desktop:

```
#Input
print askopenfile(mode="rb")

#Output
<open file u'C:/Users/User/Desktop/stuff.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x029BA078>
```

This is what happened when I printed the file and used read():

```
#Input
print askopenfile(mode="rb").read()

#Output
These are words in the file stuff.txt.
```

This document [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) gives a good idea about files and how they work. Also remember to close the file after you are done reading it to prevent other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `print self.getFileInfo` to `print self.getFileInfo()`. Remember that using parentheses is how you call the function. Also do this any other places in your code. Note that this will call the function again. You could instead do `print self.logFile` to view the results.

Comment: I have tired this the issue is this will reexecute the function again. So if I hit the compareAction button it will prompt me to choose a file. I dont want that button to do that i want it only to "do whatever is inside its function" Using the `print self.getFileInfo()` wont work for me here.

Comment: I keep getting the address of the function `<bound method myButtons.getFileInfo of <__main__.myButtons instance at 0x10a50aef0>>` when using `self.logFile` maybe I am incorrectly returning a value from the `getFileInfo` function?

Comment: did you change self.logfile=getFileInfo    to    self.logfile=getFileInfo()?

Comment: yeah. If i do that then when I start the program the getFileInfo function is executed immediately without having to press the button. and it still returns a memory address.

Comment: Sure thing. Editing it